# Heroku Login issue to get support

Tags: authentication, heroku

How to connect to Heroku support with a login problem if needs to login to get support?

The login is failed for Dashboard or CLI

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

FYI there was a password reset from Heroku a few days ago, so you may need to reset your password manually:

https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2413

Comment: I'm having this same issue and reset my password but no luck getting in, seems like nobody is complaining about it on twitter it might be a few affected users but there is no way to get help since their support is for logged in users only.

Comment: Just reset it a second time and it worked, weird. Seems like it does have to do with  a password reset.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your password. There was a PSA from Heroku last week -- advising users to change passwords. After that, you're good to go.